# Difference between frame.size.width and frame.width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, cgrect, cgsize

I was writing a program in swift and just now I noticed that I can directly access a `CGRect` frame's width and height properties directly without using the `CGSize` width and height. That is I am now able to write a code like this.

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var height = myView.frame.height
    var height1 = myView.frame.size.height
}
```

In Objective C, when I tried to write the same code, the line `height = view.frame.height` is throwing an error. Can anyone please tell me the difference(if any) in these two lines of code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just looked into the `CGRect` structure reference. In Swift there is an extension defined which have members `height` and `width`. Please have a look at the code below

```
struct CGRect {
var origin: CGPoint
var size: CGSize
}

extension CGRect {
    ...
    var width: CGFloat { get }
    var height: CGFloat { get }
    ...
}
```

So that you can directly fetch `height` and `width` values from a `CGRect`. As you can see these are only `getters`, so you will get an error if you try to set these values using `view.frame.height = someValue`

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you provide me a link to where I can find this reference. I checked the documentation but didn't see this extension anywhere :/

Comment: Hold `Command` key and hover the `Class/Variable` and then click on it.

Answer (score 2):

`frame` is of `CGRect` structure, apart from its `width` and `height` have only `getters`, they can only be **positive**. From the documentation:

*Regardless of whether the height is stored in the CGRect data structure as a positive or negative number, this function returns the height as if the rectangle were standardized. That is, the result is never a negative number.*

However, `size` is of `CGSize` structure, from the documentation:

*A CGSize structure is sometimes used to represent a **distance vector**, rather than a physical size. As a vector, its values can be **negative**. To normalize a CGRect structure so that its size is represented by positive values, call the **standardized** function.*

So the difference is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> In Objective C, when I tried to write the same code, the line `height = view.frame.height` is throwing an error. Can anyone please tell me the difference (if any) in these two lines of code.

CGGeometry.h defines a couple of types, among them the C `struct CGRect`. This struct has two members: origin and size.

That's all you can access in C (and Objective-C) using dot notation. Neither C nor Objective-C offer extensions for structs.

Swift imports the type as a Swift struct. The difference is that Swift **does** allow for extensions on structs. So it exposes several free C functions as extensions:

```
CGRectGetMinX() — CGRect.minX
CGRectGetMidX() — CGRect.midX
CGRectGetMaxX() — CGRect.maxX
CGRectGetWidth() — CGRect.width
[... same for y]
```

These C functions are there since ages—they just live in a dusty corner of CoreGraphics.

They are quite useful but you have to know their semantics (which differ a bit from the standard accessors): They normalise the dimensions.

This means that they convert a rect with negative width or height to a rect that covers the same area with positive size and offset origin.

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: -10)
assert(rect.width == rect.size.width)   // OK
assert(rect.height == rect.size.height) // boom
```