# Difference between CGSize and CGRect

Tags: ios, cgrect, cgsize

What is the difference between CGSize and CGRect?

As a beginner reading the [CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/) it wasn't immediately obvious, especially because there were references to size being a vector. I was kind of surprised that I couldn't find this basic question on StackOverflow, so I decided to research it more and post my answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## CGSize

`CGSize` is a width and a height. It is not technically considered a rectangle (which is one reason I confused it with `CGRect` in the beginning), but rather just a size. However, for the purpose of illustration, I will represent it as a rectangle below:

[image]

This combination of width and heigh is known as a struct, which is short for structure, and originally comes from the C language (but I will be using the Swift rather than Objective C syntax here). A structure is just a group of logically related variables. Here we can see the `CGSize` structure:

```
struct CGSize {
  var width: CGFloat
  var height: CGFloat
}
```

where `CGFloat` is either a `float` (32 bit) or a `double` (64 bit). (See [What's the difference between using CGFloat and float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264924/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgfloat-and-float))

You can make a `CGSize` by doing the following:

```
var size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
```

## CGRect

`CGRect` is a rectangle. What is not immediately obvious from the name, though, is that in addition to a width and a height, it also has has an origin.

[image]

`CGsize`, by comparison, does not have an origin.

`CGRect` is also a structure. If fact, it's a structure of structures: a `CGPoint` (the origin) and `CGSize` (the width and height). Here it is:

```
struct CGRect {
  var origin: CGPoint
  var size: CGSize
}
```

where `CGPoint` is

```
struct CGPoint {
  var x: CGFloat
  var y: CGFloat
}
```

You can make a `CGRect` by doing the following:

```
var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30))
```

## Negative width and height

The width and height values can be negative. We can see what this looks like with `CGRect`. Notice how the origin appears on different corners:

[image]

## Vectors

The [documentation for CGSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGSize) says

> A `CGSize` structure is sometimes used to represent a distance vector, rather than a physical size. As a vector, its values can be negative. To normalize a `CGRect` structure so that its size is represented by positive values, call the `CGRectStandardize` function.

[Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) in math have a magnitude (or length) and a direction. Although `CGSize` doesn't have an origin, you can see from the following diagram how the width and height along with their associated positive or negative values give both the length and direction.

[image]

## Further Reading

- [CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html)
- [Structures in Swift](http://www.codingexplorer.com/structures-swift/)
- [Enums and Structs in Swift](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/enums-structs-swift)
- [Big Nerd Ranch - Rectangles, Part 1](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/rectangles-part-1/)
- [CGRect, CGSize and CGPoint](http://iosdevelopertips.com/c/cgrect-cgsize-and-cgpoint.html)
- [C Structures](http://iosdevelopertips.com/c/c-structures.html)
- [Difference between frame.size.width and frame.width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243451/difference-between-frame-size-width-and-frame-width)

Comment: Great Explanation!

Answer (score 9):

Short version: Their names are confusing, because they both can be used to represent rectangles.

**CGSize** has width and height

[image]

**CGRect** has x, y, width and height

[image]

You can think of CGRect as a CGSize with coordinates.

CGRect is commonly used to specify a UIView frame, which (top, left) coordinates are relative to the (top, left) coordinates of the parent view.

[image]